# QT creator - 'QGraphicsScene' does not name a type

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene, qpixmap

I am new to QT, attempting to teach myself.

Following examples/tutorials I arrived at this code.

The purpose is creating a simple interface allowing a login.

My error:

```
mainwindow.h:22: error: 'QGraphicsScene' does not name a type
     QGraphicsScene *scene;
```

I have not found a solution but only mention of removing the object from the UI and using `this` instead of `ui->graphicsView` when instantiating the `QGraphicsScene`.

What am I missing?

**Headers/mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QGraphicsScene *scene;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**Sources/mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
//#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    scene = new QGraphicsScene(ui->graphicsView);
    scene->setSceneRect(ui->graphicsView->rect());
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
    ui->graphicsView->setFixedSize(400,400);
    QPixmap pixmap("res/logo/logo-black.png");
    scene->addPixmap(pixmap);
    ui->graphicsView->show();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

**Sources/main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**Forms/mainwindows.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>283</width>
    <height>415</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>120</x>
      <y>130</y>
      <width>141</width>
      <height>22</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_2">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>120</x>
      <y>170</y>
      <width>141</width>
      <height>22</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>90</x>
      <y>250</y>
      <width>91</width>
      <height>31</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Login</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QCheckBox" name="checkBox">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>90</x>
      <y>220</y>
      <width>101</width>
      <height>20</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Remeber Me</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>20</x>
      <y>130</y>
      <width>59</width>
      <height>14</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Email</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>20</x>
      <y>170</y>
      <width>59</width>
      <height>14</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Password</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_2">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>96</x>
      <y>310</y>
      <width>80</width>
      <height>22</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Register</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QGraphicsView" name="graphicsView">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>80</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <width>121</width>
      <height>111</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="autoFillBackground">
     <bool>false</bool>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>283</width>
     <height>19</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QToolBar" name="mainToolBar">
   <attribute name="toolBarArea">
    <enum>TopToolBarArea</enum>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="toolBarBreak">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </attribute>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar"/>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

**UPDATE**

- Uncommenting:
  `#include "ui_mainwindow.h"` in `Sources/mainwindow.cpp`

*Reason I did not see `ui_mainwindow.h` in my project directory, thus thinking it is an unnecessary include.*

- Adding 
  `#include <QGraphicsScene>` in `Headers/mainwindow.h`

*Found from [documentation page](https://www.ics.com/files/qtdocs/qgraphicsscene.html) - more of a "what will happen if I add this" attempt*, had the idea that `<QtGui>` included the `<QGraphicsScene>`

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you have to include the following:

```
#include <QGraphicsScene>
```

as stated [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qgraphicsscene.html)

Answer (score 0):

You are including unnecessary headers, and not including necessary ones. To use the widgets module, you only need to `#include <QtWidgets>`. The `mainwindow.h` file should start as follows:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QtWidgets>

namespace Ui {
  ...
```